# Integration of web app using webGL, into company's CRM

Tags: asp.net, webgl, crm

I want to develop a web application using webGL library. But, to make it run on Internet Explorer, we need IEWebGL plugin.

That's Ok. But, the main issue is that I want to integrate this application into a Company's CRM system. For that, the plugin usage would be a problem.

So, how to integrate that app into the CRM ? Please suggest some solution .

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but what CRM platform are they using?

Comment: They are using Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Comment: If you're company is okay with the IEWebGL plugin maybe they'd be okay with the Chrome frame plugin? (https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/)

Comment: Actually, i will be developing the web application. Then it has to be integrated into Microsoft Dynamics CRM. But, i have no idea as to how one can install the plugin(IEWebGL or chrome-frame) into the CRM, along with the web application.